# Whats this bindApplication method in Android running on main tread?

Tags: android, profiling, systrace

I'm using systrace to find and solve my frozen frame issues.

and I see this methood, It seem like it called by android framework while initialising.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if [this article](https://medium.com/android-news/android-application-launch-explained-from-zygote-to-your-activity-oncreate-8a8f036864b) can help?